# Several instances of HTML5 video not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have a web-page with 2 `<video>` elements on it

```
<video muted playsinline preload="auto" id="player1"></video>
<video muted playsinline preload="auto" id="player2"></video>
```

I'm setting the `src` for each of them via javascript, for the `player1`, and till 1 second for the `player2`. The `player1` start playing, but when I'm setting the src for the `player2` the first one comes to black, seems that I can't use more than one preloaded video tags on one page.

```
player1.src = <url1>;
player1.play();
//everything ok

setTimeout(() => {
  player2.src = <url2> // brokes playback
}, 1000);
```

This only fails on **old browsers** and smart TVs like Samsung and LG, maybe there are some tricks for the old ones?
This is a just very simple example but it also not working (initiating 2 video players with preloaded content on the same page)
I tried to preload with XMLHTTPRequest but got the same issue

The original idea is a seamless transition from one video to another, one player is hidden, but with a predefined src, and when the first one fires "ended" I change the visibility of the second and start it, and switch players again and again. If `preaload="none"` all works but the video tag is not preloading the first frame and there is a lag between the videos switching.

Comment: What specific browsers and devices must your app support?

Comment: I’m testing on Samsung Smart TV, TizenBrowser 4.2.11030. Also, when I convert the JS code to the LG compatible bundle, WebOS (.ipk file) it doesn’t work

Comment: Try waiting for the [canplaythrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event) event on the first video before loading the second video. You might also set the [poster](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster) attribute so that something is displayed when not playing.  I don't have a way to test on your devices, but here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhfycL6k/show) illustrating the idea.

Comment: Thank you, tried to listen this event, also tried to wait 5 seconds with setTimeout, the first video starts, plays, and when timeout resolves the first player goes to black..